# How to find key influencers variables in a formula Y=X1+X2+...+Xn?

Tags: regression, cart, boosting, trend, importance

I've been trying to find which are the key clients in a sales trend. I have the following dataset which follows the formula `Y(t) = X1+X2+...+Xn` whereas each Xi is the revenue of a client in time (t):

```
df = data.frame(y_var = c(2762000, 574500, 125800, 634280, 43000, 175000, 2707248, 55200, 59500), 
                x_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 584000, 0, 0), 
                x_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2123248, 0, 0), 
                x_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 634280, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                x_4 = c(2762000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 175000, 0, 0, 0), 
                x_5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 43000, 0, 0, 55200, 59500), 
                x_6 = c(0, 574500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                x_7 = c(0, 0, 125800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
                )
```

Each row are the sales of a product in time (t), variable `yvar` is the sum of`x_1:x_7`.

I want to build some kind of model that helps me find which are the top variables that influence this trend.

In this example, I would expect the model to give me x_4 and x_2 as key variables.
I tried to approach this with a linear regression model, but it is not good as some variables will have perfect correlation (x_1 and x_2) so one of those will not have a coefficient, hence, I will not be able to select them as key influencers.

GBM, CART, have not helped me either.

I would expect that a regression would have worked as I get the coefficient of each client and then assign its influence thanks to that, but it didn't work.

How should I approach this? I don't want to get the top sales by client, as I'm more interested in seeing if any of them is influencing in the trend change.

Comment: [tag:boruta] is one way. Lots of options and discussion can be discovered with a search. Here's one to get you started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bimportance%5d%20score%3a3%20answers%3a1

Comment: I could use the dummy-text to make an answer.  I like boruta.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a statistical model to get a sense for how each of the `x_` variables contribute to `y_sum`.

It seems something like this would work for your purposes if the idea is to determine how much each variable is contributing to the overall.

```
> colSums(df[2:8]/sum(df$y_var))
       x_1        x_2        x_3        x_4        x_5        x_6        x_7 
0.08183251 0.29751835 0.08887795 0.41154466 0.02209758 0.08050133 0.01762762
```

Also would seem to fit with your expectation that `x_2` and `x_4` is most important.